# Why is this image doen't get rotated?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I wanted to rotate an image on a html canvas before drawing. I used the following code (`ctx` is the canvas context):

```
ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 4);
var img = new Image();
img.src = "Test.png";
img.onload = function()
{
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.resetTransform();
```

I would expect the image to be rotated by 45°. This is in fact the case, if I omit the last line. But if I include the last line, the image is drawn without rotation. Why is this the case? I expected that everything after `beginPath()` is not relevant for the drawing before.

How to avoid this effect? I want to draw things after the image, and they should not be rotated at all.

Comment: put resettransform right after drawImage

Comment: @StepanYakovenko Put your answers in the answer section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `onload` function gets triggered asynchronously, when the image loaded.

The rest of your code runs while the image is loading, and resets the context before the image loaded.

Your code is like this:

```
Rotate canvas
Load an image "Test.png"
When the image loaded, run this code: { Draw the image }
While the image is loading...
Reset the rotation
```

To await the image load, move your full drawing code to that function:

```js
var img = new Image();
img.src = "Test.png";
img.onload = function()
{
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 4);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.resetTransform();
    //Draw something else after the image has loaded and drawn
}
//Draw something BEFORE image load
```

Comment: When does `onload` actually fire? When the `src` is set?

Comment: @wazz No, it fires *after* the `src` was set **and** the image is fully loaded from the server (or elsewhere).

Comment: Oh of course. But setting the src does load the image, I knew that. tnx. That event should be called `onloaded`. :)

Comment: Ah, that's the reason why. Okay, this makes my task more difficult, but at least I understand now what's going on. Thank you!